# Knockout foreach bidning not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm trying to get the Knockout foreach binding working in my code. I've done it many times before, but in this particular case I can't seem to get it right. I must be doing something wrong here, but I can't see it. I created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lc144jv/

**JavaScript:**

```
var ReportModel = function (parent) {
            var self = this;
            self.parent = parent;
            self.filters = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.addFilter = function () {
                self.filters.push({ logicOperator: 0, columnName: null, comparisonOperator: 0, value: null });
            };

            self.removeFilter = function () {
                self.filters.remove(this);
            };
        };

        var ViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.reportModel = false;

            self.init = function () {
                self.reportModel = new ReportModel(self);
            };
        };

        var viewModel;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                viewModel = new ViewModel();
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                viewModel.init();
            });
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Column</th>
                <th>Operator</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- ko foreach: reportModel.filters -->
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data_bind="value: logicOperator" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data_bind="value: columnName" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data_bind="value: comparisonOperator" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data_bind="value: value" /></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $parent.removeFilter">
                        Remove
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" style="text-align: right;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: reportModel.addFilter">
                        Add
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
```

**UPDATE**

A few notes:

1. I was using the wrong attribute: "data_bind" instead of "data-bind". I corrected it now and the updated code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lc144jv/2/
2. It's still not working even though I made that fix
3. When I copied and pasted it to a plain .html file and ran it, I could see something interesting in Firebug:

[image]

As you can see, running the following script in the command window shows there is nothing in the collection before clicking Add, and then something afterwards:

```
JSON.stringify(viewModel.reportModel.filters());
```

So the new object is in the observable array, but it's not binding to the table in the foreach block. But, why? From what I can see, everything looks fine.. but maybe I need a fresh pair of eyes on this. Someone please show me what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  At the moment you seem to be doing a foreach where there is no filter applied.  Or is that not the problem?

Comment: @brianlmerritt, thanks, but its not the problem. nothing at all shows. Try click the button and it doesnt do anything. I just noticed I was using "data_bind" instead of "data-bind" though and changed that, but its still not working. See updated code here: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lc144jv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `reportModel` after the bindings plus I had to add the function call to the buttons()    .

slight changes:

```
    var ReportModel = function (parent) {
        var self = this;
        self.parent = parent;
        self.filters = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.addFilter = function () {
            self.filters.push({ logicOperator: 0, columnName: null, comparisonOperator: 0, value: null });
        };

        self.removeFilter = function () {
            self.filters.remove(this);
        };
    };

    var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.reportModel = new ReportModel(self);

        self.init = function () {
            console.info(self);
    //self.reportModel = new ReportModel(self);
        };
    };

    var viewModel;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            viewModel = new ViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            viewModel.init();
        });
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Column</th>
                <th>Operator</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- ko foreach: reportModel.filters -->
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data_bind="value: logicOperator" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data_bind="value: columnName" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data_bind="value: comparisonOperator" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data_bind="value: value" /></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $parent.removeFilter()">
                        Remove
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" style="text-align: right;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: reportModel.addFilter()">
                        Add
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vw2kngqq/

Comment: I think your original comment was correct: it was setting bindings in the wrong location. Because i changed my fiddle to only do that (not touched the html at all) and it's working now.

Comment: If you want to `tool up` a bigger app with components and central service providers, I have an example with ES2015 and auto import of the components https://github.com/brianlmerritt/knockout-babel-browserify-gulp